# How to know Windows Partitions?

Tags: windows-7, gparted

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows, but now I want to uninstall Windows as it's now corrupted.I don't remember on which partition I have Windows installed.I have the following partitions:

- 4 ntfs
- 1 ext4
- 1 extended
- 1 linux-swap
- 2 unallocated

How to know on which partitions I have Windows?

Comment: gparted should help you identify it.

Comment: Windows default file system is NTFS. Mounting an NTFS partition and finding the Windows directory would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert but here is my best answer:

Swap: Probably previous from the 'linux' word. It works as a supporting ram for linux

```
ext4: this is your linux

Unallocated: just empty space

Extended: I don't know!

ntfs: your windows is here
```

Can you maybe tell from the space of the drive? You can also mount the drive and look at the files inside. The C:\ drive will have files such as program files and Windows.

Mounting also gives you the ability to retrieve your files if you need some files. To mount the drive you just use Gparted, right click on the drive you want to mount and click "mount" (no magic, right? xD)

Otherwise you use the terminal. First, you can find the name of the drive using fdisk

```
fdisk -l
```

You will get a list of the installed drives, here is a list of mine:

```
Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1          40     409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2      411648    1050623    638976   312M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3     1050624  206505983 205455360    98G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4   206505984  246810623  40304640  19.2G Linux swap
/dev/sda5   246810624  536717143 289906520 138.2G Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sda6   536717144  537986679   1269536 619.9M Apple boot
/dev/sda7   689291264 1456939007 767647744   366G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda8  1456939008 1465147391   8208384   3.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda9   537987072  689291263 151304192  72.2G Linux filesystem
```

The device name is /dev/sdx* (letter and number). For example, my EFI System device name is `/dev/sda1` and so on. You can determine which drive is which from the device type column. It will be either NTFS or Microsoft basic data. I will mount my EFI as an example here from terminal

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1
```

You should see the drive mounted and be able to navigate through it. After you determine your windows drive you can then delete it. I hope this answered your question

**Note:** if you want to delete windows only because the boot is corrupted after installing linux then you might want to create another question with that problems. My experience with ask.ubuntu is that people here have creative solutions for every problem!

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer, I'd suggest searching online (or looking on Wikipedia) for the various filesystems listed. For example, [the Wikipedia article on NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) will tell you whether NTFS is a Unix (or Linux) or Microsoft filesystem.